# Deep difference of two objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

How to get differences of two objects as the following:

```
Origin = {name:{en:"test",ar:"yes"}}
Copy = {name:{en:"test",ar:"No"}}
```

And result should be "difference is `name.ar="No"`

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on what you actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

It's function helps you. But there is a good [repos](https://github.com/NV/objectDiff.js) which is very useful. See [demo](http://nv.github.io/objectDiff.js/) page

```js
function getDifferenceBetweenObjects(objectA, objectB) {

  var propertyChanges = [];
  var objectGraphPath = ["this"];

  (function(a, b) {
    if (a.constructor == Array) {
      // BIG assumptions here: That both arrays are same length, that
      // the members of those arrays are _essentially_ the same, and 
      // that those array members are in the same order...
      for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        objectGraphPath.push("[" + i.toString() + "]");
        arguments.callee(a[i], b[i]);
        objectGraphPath.pop();
      }
    } else if (a.constructor == Object || (a.constructor != Number &&
        a.constructor != String && a.constructor != Date &&
        a.constructor != RegExp && a.constructor != Function &&
        a.constructor != Boolean)) {
      // we can safely assume that the objects have the 
      // same property lists, else why compare them?
      for (var property in a) {
        objectGraphPath.push(("." + property));
        if (a[property].constructor != Function) {
          arguments.callee(a[property], b[property]);
        }
        objectGraphPath.pop();
      }
    } else if (a.constructor != Function) { // filter out functions
      if (a != b) {
        propertyChanges.push({
          "Property": objectGraphPath.join(""),
          "ObjectA": a,
          "ObjectB": b
        });
      }
    }
  })(objectA, objectB);
  return propertyChanges;
}

firstObj = {
  name: {
    en: "test",
    ar: "yes"
  }
}

secondObj = {
  name: {
    en: "test",
    ar: "No"
  }
}

console.log(getDifferenceBetweenObjects(firstObj, secondObj));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response...i'ts so useful answer

Comment: this wont work in strict mode